# 'bundle update' reporting gems with no compatible version, with contradicting version requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

'bundle update' is giving me some very strange errors. arel, activemodel and rack are listed below as not having compatible versions. Each is listed twice, with contradictory version requirements:

```
$ bundle update
Updating https://github.com/bborn/communityengine.git
Updating https://github.com/bborn/authlogic.git
Updating https://github.com/paneq/calendar_date_select.git
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "arel":
  In Gemfile:
    community_engine (= 2.0.0.beta) depends on
      arel (~> 2.1.1)

    community_engine (= 2.0.0.beta) depends on
      arel (2.2.1)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    community_engine (= 2.0.0.beta) depends on
      activemodel (= 3.1.0.beta1)

    community_engine (= 2.0.0.beta) depends on
      activemodel (3.1.0.rc2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    community_engine (= 2.0.0.beta) depends on
      rack (= 1.3.2)

    community_engine (= 2.0.0.beta) depends on
      rack (1.3.3)
```

gem list shows that suitable versions are installed:

```
rack (1.3.3, 1.3.2)
arel (2.2.1, 2.1.1)
activemodel (3.1.0, 3.1.0.rc2, 3.1.0.beta1)
```

It gets even stranger. Moving the 3 additional gem lines in my Gemfile from the end to the middle (after the 'source' and 'gem rails' lines) changes the errors that bundle reports:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.1.0) depends on
      actionpack (= 3.1.0)

    community_engine (= 2.0.0.beta) depends on
      actionpack (3.1.0.rc2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    community_engine (= 2.0.0.beta) depends on
      rack (= 1.3.2)

    community_engine (= 2.0.0.beta) depends on
      rack (1.3.3)
```

The community_engine gem is certainly suspect here, and I'm pursuing answers on their forums, too. But such odd errors out of bundler warrant asking a wider audience.

Any suggestions, folks?
thx!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, on the community_engine's README.markdown (https://github.com/bborn/communityengine/blob/master/README.markdown), it says:

> Requirements:
>
> - RAILS VERSION 2.3.4 (higher versions are not yet supported)

But it looks like you're trying to use Rails 3.1?

Comment: Good catch, but that's the master branch. I'm working off the rails3 branch.